# Move a link (with a pop up div) to another div, with a drop down menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

Sorry in advance for my noobness, ;). What I want to do, eventually, is to have a "visual forum" as I call it, there may be a real name for it. Anyway, I have image I made to show others what I am thinking and maybe I can get it online to show later.

I have div with an logo, the div with the title image, then five verticle divs underneath, as in columns. The columns have images in the backgrounds, the columns (divs) each can have clickable pop up links in them. So the categories of the columns are New, In Progress, Rework, Over 30 Days, and Completed. The links are more of titles to click on, once clicked on you will see what people, as the idea and the comments, that are written in the pop up div. So, once in the pop up div, there will be a selectable list, on select it will "move" the link to another column. So say you have a idea in the New area, which I am working on, so I click it, the window pops up, I add a comment, then I can select with the drop down select list to move it to In Progress, by clicking the In Progress selection.

What I am having the hardest time with now and been searching the net for days for is the selectable list that moves the link to a different column or what I have been looking for is, "move a div to another div on select" which I haven't found a answer for.

Sorry again for my noobness, if this is too hard to do or impossible or I should look elsewhere just give me an email. Also if you want to help out and get some money from me quote me a price because this is just giving me a headache. @o@.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to make the divs draggable then you might wanna use the jquery drag and drop plugin http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/
Hope this helps. :)